# eclipse + cdt + mingw, get "undefined reference to libiconv" error

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt

My dev environment is windows xp, eclipse 3.3, cdt 4.0.3, mingw 3.17 (in fact I use [easymingwtoolkit](http://code.google.com/p/easymingwtoolkit/))

I'd like to use functions like iconv_open() or related in c lanague. I included the , then I build my source file - test.c, and I got errors: 
**gcc -octest.exe test.o
test.o: In function `code_convert':
G:\workspace\ctest\Debug/../test.c:49: undefined reference to`libiconv_open'
G:\workspace\ctest\Debug/../test.c:52: undefined reference to `libiconv'
G:\workspace\ctest\Debug/../test.c:53: undefined reference to`libiconv_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 1343  ms.**

I'm a total beginner at this, can anyone tell me what to do to check where I went wrong?
Great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the preferences you included your libraries.  You clicked a little "+" sign and wrote "libiconv", "libiconv_open", etc.  The string "lib" is automatically prefixed to libraries some time.  So instead, try "iconv" and "iconv_open" and see if that works.  If that doesn't work then find the name of the library files, (probably something like "libiconv.a") and enter in the box ":libiconv.a"  You then notice that when the linker get's called is will use the "-l:libiconv.a" parameter which tells the linker to look for that exact file name.